# XSD with enumeration giving

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I have created xsd for enumeration and complex type. My main request or .class is DeletionReq. Inside which i would like to pass Id and data. Data has enumeration type "allowedApplDataColumnNamesType" and data has other elements. I created xsd and created java class but when client try to send data it dont send all the values it only sends Ids.
could you please guide me about correct below xsd and how can i verify. I tried on line xsd validator it failed there.
I have provided update for issue and provided Error Message.
1)what can be easiest set up to send xsd data and unmarshal to check if it works on. I am working in a distributed environment and because of securities and other constraint cant send request from test project.
Error I am getting is :

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"DeletionReq"). Expected elements are <{http://abc.test.abc/delete/DeletionReq/DeletionReq-V1.0}DeletionReq>
```

Xsd code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://abc.test.abc/delete/DeletionReq/DeletionReq-V1.0"
           targetNamespace="http://abc.test.abc/delete/DeletionReq/DeletionReq-V1.0"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">    
<xs:element name="DeletionReq">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element name="data" type="tns:data" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="allowedApplDataColumnNamesType">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:enumeration value="code1" />
                                  <xs:enumeration value="code2" />
                                  <xs:enumeration value="code3" />
                                  <xs:enumeration value="code4" />
                                  <xs:enumeration value="code5" />
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="data">
              <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="dataColumnName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="dataOldValue"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="dataNewValue"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="testRecord"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element name="projId"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="allowedApplDataColumnNames" type="tns:allowedApplDataColumnNamesType"/>
            </xs:sequence>          
    </xs:complexType>
```

update1 : when Client jar sends request it is missing name space. when i try to send message from application it has namespace. because of missing namespace it throws exception. I am trying to figure out why request from client missing namespace.
update 2: the issue is in complextype "Data". when java class is generated it dont have namespace in the @xmlType. I am not sure how to add namespace in complex type i tried few attributes but unsuccessful.
Thank you

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSD that tries to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Comment: Edit your question and show us the Java code which sends data.  Also, please show us the XML that was actually sent.  It is not clear what you mean by “it only sends Ids.”

Comment: Are you getting any errors.  If not then you probably aren't adding all the values to the object.

Comment: I dont receive any errors. payload object dont have all values. object is generated using above xsd

Comment: It sounds as if you are using some kind of data binding library that tries to generate XML instances from Java objects based on the supplied schema and you aren't happy with the instances that it generates. If that's the case, then the first thing we need to know is what library you are using and how you invoke it.